# QGIS Color Ramp Apply

Tags: pyqgis, color-ramp

I have almost 100 of single band grayscale rasters. Importing all of them one by one to QGIS and changing the color ramp seems laborious. Is there any PyQgis codes/function that can apply predefined color ramp to a raster? I found multiple solutions where python defines the color ramp first then apply it to the raster. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193723/how-to-add-all-dat-files-raster-into-qgis-in-a-defined-directory-and-defin) is a great example of creating a color ramp and assigning it to raster. The CookBook has a similar example, which is -

```
>>> fcn = QgsColorRampShader()
>>> fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
>>> lst = [ QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor(0,255,0)), \
QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(255, QColor(255,255,0)) ]
>>> fcn.setColorRampItemList(lst)
>>> shader = QgsRasterShader()
>>> shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fcn)
```

However, I don't want to define the color ramp. My choice of color ramp is in predefined, which is  "RdBu" (Red to Blue) on a raster layer. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Does it need to be through PyQgis? You could always define the style for one raster, then copy the style, select all other rasters, and paste it to them all in one go.

Comment: @Cushen  If I can complete the task in a few clicks then it would be great. Do you happen to have any resources that show how to do that?

Comment: See posted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do 'Manually':

1. Add all rasters to the Canvas.
2. Apply Raster Style to One Layer >
       Right Click this layer > Styles > Copy Style
3. Select all other
       layers (shift and click to select all between two clicks) > Right
       Click > Paste Style

### **Do with Code:**

You could also save the style to a file, add all the raster layer in a folder (.tif here) to the canvas, and  then apply this style to all layers in the canvas as follows:

```
import glob, os
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
#NOTE 'PyQt4' for QGIS 2

rast_path = "C:/folderofrasters"
rasters = glob.glob(os.path.join(rast_path, "*.tif"))
print(rasters)

#to save style from a layer
#layer.saveNamedStyle(pathqml)
pathqml = 'C:/temp/rasterstyle.qml'

#ADD THE RASTER LAYERS TO THE CANVAS
for raster in rasters:
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
    path = fileInfo.filePath()
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    lyr = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)  
    #NOTE 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' for QGIS 2  

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

#APPLY THE STYLE TO ALL LAYERS IN THE CANVAS
for l in layers:
    l.loadNamedStyle(pathqml)
    l.triggerRepaint()
```